# Export to PDF script only exports the last worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA script that exports the contents of a worksheet to PDF. It worked fine with a single worksheet, but now I've been asked to have it include a second worksheet. However, using the script below now only includes the second worksheet and not the first. Can anyone advise why the first worksheet of the pair is not included?

```
Dim sheetsToPrint as Variant(1)
sheetsToPrint(0) = FirstWorksheet.Name
sheetsToPrint(1) = SecondWorksheet.Name

FirstWorksheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(FirstWorksheet.Range("B2:I10"), FirstWorksheet.UsedRange).Address

With FirstWorksheet.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = -4
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = False
End With

SecondWorksheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Union(secondPage.Range("B2:I10"), secondPage.UsedRange).Address

With SecondWorksheet.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = -4
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = False
End With

saveAndClose sheetsToPrint
```

The saveAndClose function is defined like this:

```
Private Sub saveAndClose(ByRef sheetsToPrint() As Variant)

    Sheets(sheetsToPrint).Select

    Dim primarySheetName As String
    primarySheetName = CStr(sheetsToPrint(0))


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=outputDirectoryPath & ":" & primarySheetName & ".pdf"
            Sheets(sheetsToPrint).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

This is part of a batch process, so I haven't copied all of my code, but this is the part that currently exports a PDF containing only the information from sheetsToPrint(1) but not sheetsToPrint(0). I've been banging my head on this all afternoon since as far as I can see, it's the same as every example on the internet of how to export multiple sheets to PDF.

Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong?

Comment: I ussualy have trouble working with arrays in VBA, and the problem ussualy dissapears when I use normal variables. Have you tried using variables and calling `saveAndClose` twice instead of once using arrays?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @NicholasKemp but I'd like these sheets to be exported into the same PDF file, not two separate ones. Each time this runs, it will be generating one report with two pages.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set it up like this:

```
Dim sheetsToPrint As Sheets
Set sheetsToPrint = Sheets(Array("Blad1", "Blad2", "Blad3"))
```

And then use `sheetsToPrint.select` in the saveandclose sub

Comment: Isn't that effectively what my current script does? At the point when the PDF if exported, I have already selected the sheets I want to print. I can confirm by throwing in a break point just before the export that the sheets I want are selected. It's just that only one is exported.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that the selection went wrong maybe. The only other difference I can find is that in a code I use for a similar function I use `Application.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` instead of only ActiveSheet...